# Is it possible to get LinkedIn statuses by fact of posting?

Tags: api, oauth, twitter-oauth, linkedin-api

I have an application which can get user statuses using LinkedIn API according to [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api).

But I need to know: is it possible to ask LinkedIn to signal me when described users change his status ? I think it is too waste to make API queries each 10 minutes for each my user!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no 'push' capabilities with the LinkedIn API. You would have to do periodic checks to see if there were any recent updates.